# Can not Mount "/dev/hdb on /cdrom" on Carrier i-Vu CCN

Tags: mount, kernel, hard-disk, initramfs, data-cd

I had to replace a hard drive in a Carrier I-VU HVAC Control server for a nursing home with no heat. I am not a HVAC guy but am trying to get heat back on because repairman could not get it for a week.
When I put in the Recovery CD (the disk appears to re-image the drive completely to repair it) and boot from it I get an error that it could not mount /dev/hdb. I Can not figure out why it will not see this drive; or is it another issue?
When I boot i get the following:

```
Boot from AHCI CD-Rom
1. FD 2.88MB SYSTEM Type- 00

LILO 22.7 Loading Linux
BIOS data check
Map File: WRITE PROTECT
successful

Map file: WRITE PROTECT

Decompressing Linux... done.
Booting the kernel.
mount: Mounting /dev/hdb on /cdrom failed: no such device or address
Error setting up the initial ramdisk (error:2) Exiting...
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,1)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: That really looks like an old old old version of Linux that's expecting IDE based CDROMs, but you appear to be using a SATA or USB based drive.